# Is there a way to create an all inclusive master tex file from many imported tex files

Tags: pdftex, import

I have a main tex file which includes many import statements.
I'm compiling with pdflatex to generate a PDF.

I'd like to create a new .tex file that includes all the content from the main .tex file, and includes all the content from the imported .tex files to create one master version with all content.

I was wondering if someone knew whether this was possible, or had some experience with it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! I've done this kind of thing, take a look at lines 296-304 of the following file for a demonstration : https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/blob/main/.github/workflows/build-documentation-and-executables.yaml

Comment: Thanks for the super fast responses and help! Those really helped me out.